# Google sheets onedit then ImportRange

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I did not care for the layout of Google Forms so made one (sheet named "LoadPack Form") for sales to fill out. Once completed they will hit submit and it will transfer the info onto "ENTRIES" sheet using a completed script(second bit of code).

I cannot get OnEdit trigger to work, need help. When value in "C2" on "LoadPack Form" is changed I want it to run a query on "Entries" column ("G"). the value in C2 matches what is on "ENTRIES" sheet then import the data into the Form and enter the word "UPDATE" in cell D2. Ideally & Eventually any information that is updated will be submitted back to the "ENTRIES" sheet and an email advising what did change will be sent.

My test shared spreadsheet is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vueBvqJwaD_fPp1Tos8whc8v_k0WGnOapmghIawUDhk/edit?usp=sharing

Any assistance is much appreciated. here is the start to my journey with onEdit

```
function onEdit(e) {


var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = SS.getActiveSheet();
var myRangeAddress = "C2"; // change to yours
var myRange = e.range;
var upRange = "D2"
var targetRange = ss.getRange(myRangeAddress);

if (ss.getName() == ss && RangeIntersect(targetRange, myRange)) {
  upRange.setValue("Update")

    var myVal = myRange.getValue();
    var Symbol = getSymbol(myVal);
    myRange.setValue(Symbol);
}
```

This is a short version of the function that is transposing the information from one sheet to the other which is linked to the "submit" button

```
function copyFormOnClick() {

var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1y-JyXfu5LS-ISITRToP_TEqfexrBpTSktFc-OZ3Ui7g'); var ss = sss.getSheetByName('LoadPack Form');
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1y-JyXfu5LS-ISITRToP_TEqfexrBpTSktFc-OZ3Ui7g'); var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Operations');
var  n = 1 
var  i = n+1

ts.insertRowAfter(n); //New info to Row1
ts.getRange(i,5).setValue(new Date()); // Timestamp
var RRRef = ss.getRange('C2').getValues();
ts.getRange(i,12).setValues(RRRef); 

var SalesRep = ss.getRange('E5').getValues();
ts.getRange(i,6).setValues(SalesRep); 
//and so on another several times
```

Thanks again,

Comment: Does this not work for you or other users?Also, do the execution transcript show any errors (view>execution transcript)?

Comment: copyFormOnClick works. function onEdit(e) is Not working. I cannot get any response when C2 is edited on the form

Comment: When i debug the onEdit  i get error at var myRange = e.range;                    TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 154, file "Code")

Comment: 1. You compare a `Sheet` object with its name. 2. When you use it, `upRange` is just a string, not a range. 3. If you use in-cell formulas that read where you are writing, and then you want to read the new results following a write, you need to use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` in between. 4. If you are expecting to do something after a form submission, `onEdit` is the wrong trigger. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events

Comment: This is all foreign to me, I've posted for help on Upwork. Eager to get this finished. Please contact me if you can assist